# How to refresh a home page or go to the home page with one link?

Tags: javascript, html, refresh, tumblr

Alright so here's my dilemma, I have a refresh link on my blog that refreshes the current page you're on. I want the link to, if you're on the homepage (`/`) to refresh and if you're on a different page, say `/tagged/me` to go to the homepage `/` the current html I have for the links section is:

```
<div id="linkz">
     <a href="javascript:history.go(0)" title ="refresh">refresh</a> 
   - <a href="/fask" title="fask">fask</a>
   - <a href="/tagged/me" title="face">face</a> 
   - <a href="/more" title="more">more</a></div>
```

p.s. my blog is [here](http://www.unbinded.tk) and the links are in the sidebar.

Comment: I saw in your comments that you believe links to '/' aren't refreshing.  How are you noting that behavior?  An example of this working is clicking on the stackoverflow logo in the header on this site - that links to '/', and no matter what page you're on, it loads the homepage . . .

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what your question is asking but if you want to go to the home page, just set the link to

```
<a href="/" title="Home Page">Home Page</a>
```

On every single page. No need for Javascript, just straight up HTML.

Comment: It won't refresh while on the home p[age for some reason though

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want the link to refresh to the homepage, why not just href it to the homepage? Just make it href="/".

Comment: If I have a link like that, when I click it while on the homepage, it won't refresh